Did the "Killers of the Flower Moon" train station brawl scene have any deeper historical context or significance?
Early on in the movie Killers of the Flower Moon (2023), there's this scene right after Ernest Burkhart (played by Leonardo DiCaprio) arrives at a train station in the Osage Nation Reservation in Oklahoma.
As soon as he gets there, we see this group of people just straight-up brawling with each other, throwing punches and everything, while a bunch of bystanders are just standing around like it's no big deal.

Weirdly enough, Ernest doesn't even bat an eye at this chaos happening in front of him. In fact, he actually joins in on the fight and seems to be getting a kick out of the whole thing.
I can't help but feel like I'm missing some deeper meaning or historical context behind this random outbreak of violence at a train station.
Was this kind of public brawling just a normal occurrence back then that people treated nonchalantly, or was there more to this scene that went over my head?

"I can't help but feel like I'm missing some deeper meaning or historical context behind this random outbreak of violence at a train station.": a brawl can have multiple reasons and different origins, but I'd say, as very often, that the context is greed. At that time, Osages were the richest people in the world per capita, and they had to have someone look over their wealth as part of a system of guardianship (by non-Osage people, of course, mostly white...). What can start a fight then?
